# Problem running a Django program on VS Code

Tags: python, django, github, visual-studio-code

I just started working on a project that runs on Python Django. I cloned the repository from GitHub and am running python 3.9 on my computer. I set up a virtual environment on the VS Code terminal and installed Django (this is my first time using Django). I selected the interpreter for my virtual environment, however when I try to run the code (which should show a local webpage) I get the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'`.
Then I tried installing maplotlib with `pip install matplotlib` however that gives me the error `ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.`  I know there are already questions about this specific error on here but I can't seem to fix it. Would there have been an easier way to do this or did I do something wrong during my setup? I would appreciate any help! I was also told there should be a .git file when cloning the project, but that isn't there either, does that change anything?

Comment: Man download pycharm in this case, there is community edition it is free and it is the best  stuff on the market.

Comment: @ThunderHorn Thanks I'll try pycharm, how does it work with django and all that? Also I'm pretty new to GitHub so would I just have to clone and install Django and it should work?

Comment: add me on discord ThunderHorn#9059 I will explain you what to do

Comment: Sent the request, thanks